# Unable to delete a row on button click dynamically using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am adding a row with input boxes on button click in a table. However, my goal is to be able to delete a specific row when i click on the delete button in that specific row. For some reason, nothing happens. What could i be doing wrong?

```
  $("#btns").click(function (e) {
                i++;
                e.preventDefault();
             //   console.log("clicked");
                $("#items").append('<div><tr><td><input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>&nbsp<tr><td><input type="text" name="age"></td></tr>&nbsp<tr><td><input type="text" name="dob"></tr></td></div><button type="button" id="delete"+i>Delete</button><br>');


            });

            $("#delete"+i).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                console.log("clicked")
             //   $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();


            })
```

Comment: Your HTML code would be nice to see.

Answer (score 0):

A click is an event. You should listen to the delete button click event separately. Also, there could be only one id with this name - delete. If there are many delete buttons you should get them as an array of .delete class or with different ids: delte1, delete2.